# Insert array of unspecified length in MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

It's far from perfect, but I'm trying to create a function to insert data into a SQL table, using MySQLI. I want to create a generic function, to insert different types of data in different databases. I have the following so far:

```
/**
 * Add data to specified table. Data consist of column name as key, and value.
 * Table is a string of the table to insert into.
 * @param array $data
 * @param string $table
 * @return string
 */
private function insert( $data = array(), $table = null ){

    foreach( $data as $key => $value ){

        // Create arrays of separate keys and values
        $keys[]     = $key;
        $values[]   = $value;

        // Get type of data
        switch( gettype( $value ) ){
            case "integer":
                $types[]    = "i";
                break;
            case "string":
                $types[]    = "s";
                break;
            default:
                $types[]    = "i";
                break;
        };

        // for each variable, add a questionmark
        $vars[]     = "?";

    }

    // Create strings out of the data
    $key    = implode( ",", $keys );
    $var    = implode( ",", $vars );
    $type   = implode( "", $types );
    $value  = '"' . implode( '\", \"', $values ) . '"';

    // prepare SQL statement
    // var_dump( $sql ) = 'INSERT INTO table (var1,var2,var3) VALUES (?,?,?)'
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . $key . ") VALUES (" . $var . ")";

    // Prepare SQL insert
    // $this->conn = new mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
    if( ! ( $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $sql ) ) ) {
        return "Preparing failed!: (" . $this->conn->errno . ") " . $this->conn->error;
    }

    // Bind parameters. THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS!
    if( ! $stmt->bind_param( $type, $values ) ) {
        return "Binding failed! (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;;
    }

    // Execute the statement
    if( ! $stmt->execute() ){
        return "Executing failed! (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;;
    }

}
```

The issue is at binding the parameters. I can't find a good way to bind them, as I've got multiple variables with values and keys, but they're all in array format, and `bind_param` requires a new variable for each

In short, I'm looking for a way to add an array of unspecified length into my SQL (in a secure way, ofcourse).

Comment: FYI, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, I still got to look into that. I'm aware of it though, as I've not put much time into that yet. It's probably better to do that while writing, but I was still working on it. Thanks for the heads up though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using php 5.6+, you can use the `...` operator to unpack an array.

In your example:

```
$stmt->bind_param( $type, ...$values )
```

See example #14 in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-145).

Comment: Wow, if I would've known it was this easy! This is great stuff. Thanks. I will accept when I'm able (unless something better comes along, ofcourse)

Comment: That `...` rings a distant bell and I can't remember... oh wait I just remembered (as I was typing this, it came back to me); PERL/CGI. I had used that exact syntax for something I was working on years ago. Nice to see you can use that in PHP. Edit: Then again, it might have been `..` *lol*, but it's close enough ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll have to admit I'm very glad that PERL/CGI is not more than a very distant memory of many many years ago ;-)

Comment: @jeroen Not as widely used anymore as it should (I take it) but indeed not forgotten. I still use those for special purposes. I learned PERL/CGI before PHP, I just don't use it as much as I used to.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Same here but I don't use it any more. Perhaps it just looked hard as it was my first experience with server-side programming. At the time PHP was a nice improvement at least.

Comment: @jeroen Well, I can't say that "it" isn't used anymore. I wrote a special application for someone years ago and is still being used to this day. There were certain limitations (still are) on the server with PHP so I had to resort to PERL. For some silly reason that the host it's on, can't update their version of PHP. They said it was due to security reasons. So there's (always) more than one way to skin a rabbit "as it were" ;-) Gotta love \*NIX though!

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
$a_params = array();

$param_type = '';
$n = count($a_param_type);
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
  $param_type .= $a_param_type[$i];
}

/* with call_user_func_array, array params must be passed by reference */
$a_params[] = & $param_type;

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
  /* with call_user_func_array, array params must be passed by reference */
  $a_params[] = & $a_bind_params[$i];
}

/* Prepare statement */
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

/* use call_user_func_array, as $stmt->bind_param('s', $param); does not accept params array */
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $a_params);

/* Execute statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* Fetch result to array */
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  array_push($a_data, $row);
}
```

Reference: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: A very good solution, but not as easy as the one given by Jeroen.